# How to populate multiple select on the same form in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I'm currently developing a form in Laravel and having a bit of a problem wrapping my head around the whole MVC model. You see, my application deals with "problem assignment" (kind of ironic given my first statement lol). So I have a table in my database called tblProblems filled out like this:

```
1 Problem1, cat1
2 Problem2, cat2
3 Problem3, cat1
4 Problem4, cat2
...
```

The fields are ProblemID, ProblemName and Category. I also have a table called tblCities which is basically a table with two fields, CityID and CityName, setup like this:

```
1 City1
2 City2
3 City3
...
```

Now what I want to do is on my member form, I'd like to setup three "select" controls which will list problems of the first and second category as well as list the cities available.

The first thing I did was to create two models like so:

```
class Problem extends Eloquent 
{

    protected $table = 'tblProblems';
    protected $primaryKey = 'ProblemID';
    public $timestamps = false;

    public function getProblemsByCategory($cat)
    {
        return $this->where('Category', '=', $cat)->lists('ProblemName', 'ProblemID');
    }
}

class City extends Eloquent
{
    protected $table = 'tblCities';
    protected $primaryKey = 'CityID';
    public $timestamps = false;

    public function getAllCities()
    {
        return $this->orderBy('CityName', 'asc')->lists('CityName', 'CityID');
    }
}
```

Then, of course, I went ahead and added the appropriate controllers to the fray, like this:

```
class ProblemController extends BaseController
{
    protected $problems;

    public function __construct(Problem $problem)
    {
        $this->problems = $problem;
    }

    public function getProblemList($cat)
    {
        $problemList = $this->problems->getProblemsByCategory($cat);
        return View::make('testProblem', $problemList);
    }
}

class CityController extends BaseController
{
    protected $city;

    public function __construct(City $city)
    {
        $this->city = $city;
    }

    public function getCityList()
    {
        $cityList = $this->city->getAllCities();
        return View::make('testCity', $cityList);
    }
}
```

Now is where I basically got stuck. I have this in my routes.php:

```
Route::get('member', function()
{
  return View::make('memberForm');
});

Route::get('testProblem/{cat}', ProblemController@getProblemList);
Route::get('testCity', CityController@getCityList);
```

If I trigger my routes manually by entering proper URL in a browser, I can tell my code works as the proper variables become accessible to my test views with the correct content. The problem is that I can't figure out how to make all three lists available to my memberForm at the same time. Hell, I can't even figure out how to make ONE of these lists available to my memberForm.

Can anyone help me? I know the solution's probably staring at me right in the face, but for the life of me, I can't seem to figure it out.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of having a route and controller action for each list, you just want to run the queries and pass the results to the form view. Something like this:

```
Route::get('member', 'MemberController@showForm');

class MemberController extends BaseController {

    public function showForm(){
        $problemsCat1 = $this->problems->getProblemsByCategory(1);
        $problemsCat2 = $this->problems->getProblemsByCategory(2);
        $cities = $this->city->getAllCitites();
        return View::make('memberForm', compact('problemsCat1', 'problemsCat2', 'cities'));
    }
}
```

And then use it in the `memberForm` view just like any PHP variable:

```
$problemsCat1
$problemsCat2
$cities
```